# Is 'LIMIT OFFSET' stable when new element inserted?

Tags: sql, limit, offset

Let's think about a scenario.

There are 1000 rows in a table.

I queried rows with LIMIT 100.

After the query, some rows inserted in the table.

Then, I queried again, with LIMIT 100 and OFFSET 100.

I expect the result is independent of thr first query.

I want a result following first query.

How can I do this? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL standard makes no promise regarding the natural ordering of rows in a table - new rows may be inserted at the end of a table or anywhere in the middle. Depending on where your dbms inserted the rows, which will likely depend on what rows were previously deleted, your second query could easily select rows already selected in the first query, or skip some rows between queries.

The only way I can think to do what you want reliably is to select the entire table into a temporary table, or a cursor, and then read records 100 at a time from that second record set.

You could also perform all your queries within a single serializable transaction (which would hide any inserts or deletes performed by other users for the duration of your transaction) but even that would not be a foolproof solution.